# Using Wordpress Duplicator in Xampp causing errors

Tags: wordpress, xampp

I'm attempting to migrate a Wordpress site from a hosting provider to my local environment (xampp).

However, after running the installer.php, I receive the following errors/warnings when I try to do anything with the site. Is it possibly a Wordpress version or php conflict? All of these plugins work perfectly on the hosting site today.

Warning: Declaration of aec_contributor_list::form() should be compatible with WP_Widget::form($instance) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/dr/wp-content/plugins/ajax-event-calendar/inc/widget-contributors.php on line 64

Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in /opt/lampp/htdocs/dr/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/operations.class.php on line 2159

Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in /opt/lampp/htdocs/dr/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/operations.class.php on line 2163

Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in /opt/lampp/htdocs/dr/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/output.class.php on line 2803

Warning: Declaration of dropdown_menu_walker::start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) should be compatible with Walker_Nav_Menu::start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = Array, $id = 0) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/dr/wp-content/themes/sport-child/functions.php on line 124

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's the issue when moving to PHP 7.3, but it just a warning. I think there's two workaround you can do:

1. Disable the Rev Slider, AJAX event calendar plugin before taking a snapshot with Duplicator.
2. Downgrade to PHP 7.2 to taking a snapshot with Duplicator.